# Prevent "::after" untill `transition` is done

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I am creating a button which when hovered increases it witdth and then a `>` symbol appears. I can't understand how to accomplish this. I have implemented all things but the only thing that is not working is, the `>` shows up as soon as hovered and the text gets wrapped.

```
.start-quiz > button {
text-align: left;
padding-left: 25px;
width: 100px;
}

.start-quiz > button:hover {
width: 125px;
transition: width 0.5s linear;
}

.start-quiz > button:hover:after {
content: " >";
transition: content 0.5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`content` is not transition-able. You can set a opacity and than define the transition for it like so

```css
.start-quiz > button {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
}

.start-quiz > button:hover {
  width: 125px;
  transition: width 0.5s linear;
}

.start-quiz > button:after {
  content: " >";
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.start-quiz > button:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```